# Can't upload sketch to Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino

I just bought an Arduino Uno (brand new, just opened it now), and the compiler keeps saying "avrdude: usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb"". Does anyone know why?

I'm running Windows 8 x64

Comment: I'm not an Arduino user but that sounds like it's generally not recognising the USB interface or a driver isn't being loaded. Try opening the device manager, see if it updates when you connect the Uno and if so see if you can find and check the device status.

Comment: Ahh, yes. It says "The device's driver is not installed"

Comment: I don't know if this information is still current but check the second last post here: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=94651.30 - it looks like an unsigned driver problem. If those steps work you could make a note of what you had to do as you go along and post as an answer.

Comment: close, but what I did to fix the issue was slightly different - I disabled signed driver enforcement and then I used the "have disk" option and selected the folder containing arduino.inf driver file. Will post official in depth answer when I get access to a computer

Answer (score 1):

The AVR Dude compiler that Arduino uses has some issues with windows 8, but it may be that you installed the device driver incorrectly. If so you should go into the device manager, and click the 'update driver software' on the Arduino Uno. Then browse to find the driver manually and select the 'drivers' folder from where you installed the arduino IDE. If after installing the drivers it still doesn't work, then it is probably an issue with AVR Dude and you should e-mail the Arduino people. Good luck!

Comment: AVR Dude is not a compiler. It is a programming tool. The compiler is a completely separate part (avr-gcc).

Comment: Also, The "arduino people" are not responsible for avr dude. You need to e-mail the people who write avr dude. It's a completely separate tool, and just distributed as part of the arduino package.

Comment: Windows 8 is just as compatible with arduino as other versions, it's just the driver installation process is different and slightly more in depth than what's mentioned in the user manual

Answer (score 0):

The avrdude command line specifies the USB device to which the Arduino is attached. That error message means the OS doesn't see any USB device called "usb". Check that the name in the avrdude command line matches the name your Uno's USB identifies itself to the OS. And of course, that the Uno USB is properly connected.